# How to embed a limesurvey survey in my HTML without iframe

Tags: html, iframe, embed, limesurvey

I created a page to host some forms served by a limesurvey instance. For instance I used an iframe to embed them. But it created some problems. The worst is that in the second question group, which is smaller, the parent focus should go to the page top, otherwise the page appears clear because the form content was rendered on the top, and the iframe size was not resized.
Maybe it is just a limitation of mine dealing with iframe. But it would be nice if limesurvey offer other ways to embed surveys.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how to do it without Iframes on 2+ version.

The problem of multiple pages surveys standing on the bottom of the page can be handled with a small javascript workaround:

Edit the survey and add the following code at 'edit text elements' (toggle to 'source' mode at wysiwyg editor):

```
<a id="top" name="top"></a> <script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        window.location.hash = 'top';
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```